# How can I handle arrow keys in a custom component in delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard, custom-controls, delphi-xe

I'm using delphi XE.
I'm developing a component that is come from TPanel. `TApGUITab=class(Tpanel)`
I handled key down event by handling WMKeyDown message, but it isn't called when I press arrow keys and it sets focus to another control instead of calling the event.
What should I do now?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to descend from `TPanel`? Normally, when you develop custom (windowed) controls, you let them descend from `TCustomControl`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy. Just respond to the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message and return

```
Message.Result := Message.Result or DLGC_WANTCHARS or
                                     DLGC_WANTARROWS or DLGC_WANTTAB or
                                     DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
```

Comment: Thank you mate. Just the RIGHT answer.